# Should I create Push PubSub Subscription once or periodically?

Tags: publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm implementing a queue for ingesting data using PubSub Topics.
My plan is to use Push subscriptions to get data processed instantaneously as it is published.

When using a Pull Sub, I've seen a lot of code patterns trying to recreate a Pull Subscription in every run to guarantee that we have a active subscriptions in the next pull cycle.

Should I do the same using Push subscriptions? IMHO no, but I fear that in someway Push subscriptions aren't eternal and should be monitored to guarantee a active Push Subscription next time a message is published.

What is a good design pattern for Push Subscription creation?
Should I create a Push Subscription once using PubSub Admin Interface or create (or even recreate) programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason subscribers would tend to recreate the code on startup likely revolves around the fact that subscriptions are garbage collected if their presence has not been detected for 30 days (see "Are messages durable or persistent if the subscriber is not present?" in the [Google Cloud Pub/Sub FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/faq). Additionally, if a pull subscription is explicitly deleted, recreating it on startup in code ensures that the pull requests will not fail. For pull subscribers, the notion of detecting presence is fairly straightforward: check for calls to Pull.

For push subscribers, it's a little more ambiguous. If one were to delete the subscription, the subscriber itself would have no way to know it was deleted; it would simply stop receiving messages. If you are sure you will not delete subscriptions manually and will be sending at least one message every 30 days, you shouldn't need to worry about creating your subscription on startup and you can just create it once via the Pub/Sub Admin Interface.

If you wanted to alert to be sure, you could [create a policy in Stackdriver](https://app.google.stackdriver.com/policy-advanced/create) to notify when your subscription hasn't had any messages pushed to it for some period of time (assuming you publish a fairly constant stream messages). Add a condition for "Metric Absence" and choose "Cloud Pub/Sub Subscription" as the resource type, the name of the subscription, and "Push Request Count" as the trigger metric.